# Synchronize in-memory objects via network

Tags: c++, synchronization

Say we have two machines (or possibly a server with a couple of clients) connected over LAN with Linux. I want to have in-memory structure (e.g. tree-like) wich will change its member(s) on remote machine when value(s) is changed on my machine and vice versa. When some value changes some event (e.g. Qt signal) should be raised. There also should be lists/tables which are also synchronized when adding/removing elements.
  The best would be to have some framework which allows to wrap members of existent C++ classes to make them syncronizable. But all options are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any specific libraries that let you wrap C++ classes and synchronize them automatically on a network (I vaguely recall one, but I don't remember the name). However, I have played around with Qxt, and they have a nicely-done RPC framework. If you are using Qt already, it might be worth a look. http://libqxt.bitbucket.org/doc/0.6/qxtnetwork.html I have gotten the RPCs to work with a quick test on my LAN. However, I don't have any personal experience with them in terms of external connections, reliability for heavy-use, etc. So you might want to do some case-specific testing before you deploy this in any sort of production environment.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Qt so this is much helpful. But I can see only client class in docs by your link, where is a server implementation?

Comment: @VladimirLenin From the QxtRPCPeer docs: _As a QxtRPCService subclass, QxtRPCPeer can act as a client or a server. When acting as a server, it uses a QxtTcpConnectionManager to accept connections. When acting as a client, applications may use connect() to establish a TCP connection with a server._

Answer (score 0):

To communicate between multiple machines I would say use ZeroMQ library.  It has an example of  a publisher (http://zguide.zeromq.org/cpp:syncpub) and subscriber (http://zguide.zeromq.org/cpp:syncpub) that shows how to send/receive updates from different machine.